# AngualrJS - What is a Modal

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I read in a lot of the forums and support websites about modal used/defined in angularJS apps.

I don't mean module and surely not model.

Can anyone tell me more about what the modal is?

Thanks,

Comment: @andrew I wasn't asking for what a model means (read the questions).

Comment: [First result](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) of Google-search "angular modal"

Comment: Did you try googling "modal"? It gives pretty straightforward results.

Comment: Thanks to all the extremely smart people above who took the opportunity to demonstrate their Google Search skills :)

Comment: quick and precise, you saw?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Modal plugin is a dialog box/popup window that is displayed on top of the current page:

From http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

You can use it through angular with bootstrap for angular here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Ionic offers modals too: [$ionicModal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/)

Comment: Thank you David...this answers the question.